# How to select both text from same class?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using JQuery and I wanna show html from same divs. Example:

```html
<div class="content" contenteditable></div>
<div class="content" contenteditable></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

```js
$('.content').keyup(function() {
  $('#result').html($('.content').html());
});
```

In this code I take only first div's text, if I use `$(this)` instead of `$('.content')`, I take last div's text. So I can't solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Use `$(this).html()`

Comment: you want html from both divs?

Comment: I used `$(this).html()` and I took only last div's text

Comment: @NegiRox yes. from both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$('.content')** always return an array so you need to loop it

```
 $('.content').keyup(function() {
  var htmlcontent='';
  $(".content").each(function(){
    htmlcontent+=$(this).html();
  })
  $('#result').html(htmlcontent);
});
```